# How to extract data from a file and construct a filename from one of the values

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, string

I'm trying to pull two values from a configuration file and write them to a new file. The hard part is that I want the name of the new file to be determined by one of the values in the input file.

The values I'm trying to pull are "Build_Version" and the four-letter acronym from the Docker name ("docker_Name").  For example, if the file says `docker_Name='bcbs_pr-app-01'`, I want only the "bcbs". And I want to write them to a file with the build's name, such as `bcbs_build.txt`.

Here is an excerpt from the log file:

```
nonSSL_port=80  # FOR STAGING 
Build_Type=prod 
Build_Version=9.0.00.01_134143 
docker_Name='bcbs-pr-app-01'
```

The desired file output is

```
bcbs
9.0.00.01_134143
```

I came up with a `sed` command that worked for pulling the values I wanted

```
sed -n -e '/Build_Version=/p' -e '/docker_Name=/p' environment-info.conf > build_version.txt
```

but this extracts the `Build_Version=` and `docker_Name=` lines in their entirety, and I want only the Build_Version and docker name values.
And I still need to figure out how to name the file with the four-letter Docker name acronym (bcbs).

Comment: You show an example input file with Build_Version followed by docker_Name, but an output with docker_Name followed by Build_Version. Do you always want the output in the order docker_Name, Build_Version, regardless of the order in the input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file looks like `sh` syntax. So, if that file is indeed a configuration file intended to be sourced in `sh` scripts, just do:

```
. ./environment-info.conf &&
  printf '%s\n' "${docker_Name%%-*}" "$Build_Version" > "${docker_Name%%-*}_build.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you!  By adding a redirect using the variable "${docker_Name%%-*}" , it worked perfectly!  Here's what I did with your script:    ./environment-info.conf &&
  printf '%s\n' "${docker_Name%%-*}" "$Build_Version" > ${docker_Name%%-*}.txt

Comment: Sure, this is short and simple, but I'm surprised to see you recommending executing the contents of a data file without labeling the suggestion with warnings.

Answer (score 1):

1) alternating your `sed`, to a) remove first single quote of `docker_Name`, b) remove `-pr-app-01'` (including the last single quote), c) remove the `<value>=` part:

```
 sed -n "/Build_Version=/s/.*=//p;/docker_Name=/s/.*=//;s/'//;s/-.*//p"
```

Where `/match/s/pattern/replacement/` replaces `pattern` with `replacement` at a `match`ing line. If `replacement` is an empty string, it is effectively removed. Note that I switched from single to double quotes to handle the single quote in your string and that you can use wildcards `* .` to match more complex strings and combine `sed` commands with a semi-colon.

2) We read in the two results as a `BASH` array:

```
values=( $( sed -n "/Build_Version=/s/.*=//p;/docker_Name=/s/.*=//;s/'//;s/-.*//p" file ) )
```

Where `array=( value1 value2 value3 )` and `$(do this command)`

3) We use the array for our purposes, note that the counter starts at `0`:

```
echo ${values[1]} > ${values[1]}
echo ${values[0]} >> ${values[1]}
```

Where we address an entry of an array via the array name and the intex of the entry `${array[intex]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `sed` for this? `grep` and `perl` can do what you need.

```
grep 'Build_Type\|docker_Name' environment-info.conf | perl -pe "s|docker_Name='(.*?)-.*|docker_Name=\1|" > build_version.txt
```

Comment: if you're already using `perl`, you don't need grep as well.  `perl` can do everything `grep` can do and more.  Also this doesn't address the OP's requirement to name the output file based on the docker_Name variable in the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nr "s/^Build_Version=([^=]+)$/\1/p; s/^docker_Name='([^-]+).*/\1/p" file.txt
```

We are using capturing groups to get desired portions from the relevant lines. It has two parts:

- `s/^Build_Version=([^=]+)$/\1/` gets us `9.0.00.01_134143`
- `s/^docker_Name='([^-]+).*/\1/` gets us `bcbs`

To save the output to `build_version.txt`:

```
sed -nr "s/^Build_Version=([^=]+)$/\1/p; s/^docker_Name='([^-]+).*/\1/p" \
        file.txt >build_version.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
nonSSL_port=80  # FOR STAGING 
Build_Type=prod 
Build_Version=9.0.00.01_134143 
docker_Name='bcbs-pr-app-01'

% sed -nr "s/^Build_Version=([^=]+)$/\1/p; s/^docker_Name='([^-]+).*/\1/p" file.txt
9.0.00.01_134143 
bcbs
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to name the file with four letters from docker name. That can be achieved by the below command, which will assign the four letters to a variable called File_Name.

```
File_Name=`cat file | grep "docker_Name" | awk -F"'" '{print $2}' | awk -F'-' '{print $1}'`
```

As mentioned in above answers below command will assign the docker_Name and build_version to an array called values:

```
values=($(sed -n "/docker_Name=/s/.*=//;s/'//;s/-.*//p;/Build_Version=/s/.*=//p" file))
```

We are accessing the array in reverse order to capture the output the way you want:

```
for i in 1 0; do echo ${values[$i]} >> $File_Name.txt; done
```

File will be ready with name you want and cat will display its content:

```
% cat bcbs.txt
bcbs
9.0.00.01_134143
```

Comment: I believe that the OP wants the output in the order docker_Name, Build_Version, ***regardless of*** the order in the input file — not always the *reverse* of the order in the input file.